# Getting the ApplyPhase count from Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapping, burn, wix3.8

I need to calculate the progress percentage for my bootstrapper installer. But I cannot determine how many phases an install or uninstall process contains. Seems like install phase is having 2(Cache and Execute) while uninstall phase is having only 1 (Execute). But how can I get this value? In previous version I could get it from ApplyPhaseCount call back. But now it has been replaced with ApplyBegin. The parameter "ApplyBeginEventArgs" doesn't contain a count like ApplyPhase did. I can only see a Result attribute to "ApplyBeginEventArgs". How can I get this count? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase count information was added in v3.9.616.0 and v4.0.2220.0.

From v3 WixBA [ProgressViewModel](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/Setup/WixBA/ProgressViewModel.cs)

```
WixBA.Model.Bootstrapper.ApplyPhaseCount += this.ApplyPhaseCount;

private void ApplyPhaseCount(object sender, ApplyPhaseCountArgs e) 
{ 
    this.progressPhases = e.PhaseCount; 
}
```

From v4 WixBA [ProgressViewModel](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/blob/develop/src/Setup/WixBA/ProgressViewModel.cs)

```
WixBA.Model.Bootstrapper.ApplyBegin += this.ApplyBegin;

private void ApplyBegin(object sender, ApplyBeginEventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.progressPhases = e.PhaseCount; 
}
```

Comment: Okay I think the issue is, I am having Wix 3.8. I will update and let you know the status :)

Comment: Hey where is WixBA.Model.Bootstrapper class available from? I'm using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper;